# Filtrar una tabla y ocultar campos a partir de dos input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una `<tabla>` con valores de la que quiero filtrar resultados a partir de los valores inseridos en dos `<input>` el primero filtra por una columna y el segundo filtra cualquier valor igual encontrado en la tabla.

Las filas que no contengan estos valores las oculto con **CSS** añadiendo las clases `diplay:none` y `display:block`. Esto lo hace bien pero lo que sucede es que si filtro por el primer `input` y luego estos resultados los quiero filtrar por un criterio adicional en el segundo con mi función, este lo que hace es mostrarme las filas que tenia ocultas y volver a filtrarme la tabla.

Probé añadiendo diferentes clases con el `clasList.add()` pero cuando cambio el criterio de búsqueda no me vuelve a mostrar las filas ocultas y creo que con el `claslist.add()` complicaría la función un poco. ¿Qué pudiera hacer en este caso?

Gracias de antemano.

```js
function buscarCapitulo(input){

  var capitulo = (input.value).toLowerCase().trim();
  var filas = document.getElementById("tabla").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows;
    
  for(var i =0; i<filas.length; i++){   
    var textofila = (filas[i].cells[1].innerText).toLowerCase();
    filas[i].className = (textofila.indexOf(capitulo)>=0) ? "mostrar" : "ocultar";
        
  }
}

function buscarDescripcion(input){
  var descripcion = (input.value).toLowerCase().trim();
  var filas = document.getElementById("tabla").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows;
    
  for(var i =0; i<filas.length; i++){   
    var textofila = (filas[i].innerText).toLowerCase();
    filas[i].className = (textofila.indexOf(descripcion)>=0) ? "mostrar" : "ocultar";
        
  }
}


window.addEventListener('load', function(){

  var inputCapitulo = document.getElementById("buscarPorCapitulo");

  inputCapitulo.onkeyup =function(){
    buscarCapitulo(this);
  }

  var inputDescripcion = this.document.getElementById("buscarPorDescripcion");

  inputDescripcion.onkeyup = function(){
    buscarDescripcion(this);
  }
});
```

```css
.mostrar{
    display: table-row;
}

.ocultar{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for='capitolo'>Filtrar por Capitulo</label>
    <input name='capitolo' id="buscarPorCapitulo" type="number">

    <label for='descrizione'>Filtrar por una Descripcion</label>
    <input name="descrizione" id="buscarPorDescripcion" type="text">

    <br>

    <table border="1" id="tabla">
  <thead>
   <tr id="encabezado">
                <th>Anno</th>
                <th>Capitulo</th>
                <th>Importe</th>
                <th>%</th>
                <th>% iva</th></tr>
  </thead>
        <tbody id="table-data">
            <tr>
                <td>2019</td><td>123</td><td>548</td><td>5.00</td><td>21.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2019</td><td>134</td><td>2456</td><td>10.00</td><td>21.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2019</td><td>345</td><td>11111</td><td>5.00</td><td>21.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Prueba con `DataTables`, en [este enlace](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html) encuentras un ejemplo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haciendo unos pequeños cambios en el código podrías conseguir lo que te propones. Según he entendido quieres que se muestren las filas cuyo contenido coincida con los dos criterios de búsqueda que marcan sendos `<input>`.

Para ello lo que necesitas es:

> > Muéstrame lo que coincida con criterio de búsqueda 1 y que además coincida con criterio de búsqueda 2.

Lo que he hecho es encapsular todo en la misma función, a la cual llama cada uno de los `<input>` al pulsar una tecla. Una vez salta el evento capturo el contenido de ambos `<input>` y muestro solamente las filas donde ambos criterios de búsqueda se cumplan.

También modifiqué la clase **CSS** con la que mostrabas la fila, ya que al darle un `display: block` alterabas su `display` nativo mostrándose fea la tabla (el display nativo de los `<tr>` es `display: table-row`).

```js
function buscar() {
  var capitulo = (buscarPorCapitulo.value).toLowerCase().trim();
  var descripcion = (buscarPorDescripcion.value).toLowerCase().trim();
  
  var filas = document.getElementById("tabla").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows;
    
  for(var i =0; i<filas.length; i++){   
    var textofila = (filas[i].innerText).toLowerCase();
    var textocolumna = (filas[i].cells[1].innerText).toLowerCase();
    
    if (textocolumna.indexOf(capitulo) >= 0 && textofila.indexOf(descripcion) >= 0) {
      filas[i].className = 'mostrar';
    }
    else {
      filas[i].className = 'ocultar';
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){

  var inputCapitulo = document.getElementById("buscarPorCapitulo");

  inputCapitulo.onkeyup =function(){
    buscar();
  }

  var inputDescripcion = this.document.getElementById("buscarPorDescripcion");

  inputDescripcion.onkeyup = function(){
    buscar();
  }
});
```

```css
.mostrar{
    display: table-row;
}

.ocultar{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for='capitolo'>Filtrar por Capitulo</label>
    <input name='capitolo' id="buscarPorCapitulo" type="number">

    <label for='descrizione'>Filtrar por una Descripcion</label>
    <input name="descrizione" id="buscarPorDescripcion" type="text">

    <br>

    <table border="1" id="tabla">
  <thead>
   <tr id="encabezado">
                <th>Anno</th>
                <th>Capitulo</th>
                <th>Importe</th>
                <th>%</th>
                <th>% iva</th></tr>
  </thead>
        <tbody id="table-data">
            <tr>
                <td>2019</td><td>123</td><td>548</td><td>5.00</td><td>21.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2019</td><td>134</td><td>2456</td><td>10.00</td><td>21.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td><td>345</td><td>11111</td><td>5.00</td><td>21.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! @phpMyGuel  exactamente era eso lo q queria hacer...

Comment: solo un detalle el filtrar por capitulo ahora no esta filtrandome correctamente unicamente por los campos de la columna capitulo...

Comment: Ponme un ejemplo de las filas que quieres que se muestren al poner unos valores determinados en los `<input>` porque no entiendo muy bien a lo que te refieres.

Comment: El filtrar por la columna capitulo... solo adicione var textocolumna = (filas[i].cells[1].innerText).toLowerCase(); a tu respuesta y perfecto.. gracias